# Showing two Y-axis Labels in Horizantal Chart Bars

Tags: matplotlib, bar-chart, axis-labels

What I am trying to do is to put two y labels to my horizantal bar chart.Y-axis labels should be like,

Spain
Madrid (First the country name and under the country name, city name placed)

I want to show y-axis labels placed into the bars. I write below code but I couldn't be able to use both country and city names for the y axis.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
city=["Madrid","Toronto","New York","Berlin"]
country=["Spain","Canada","USA","Germany"]
values=[10500,9000,8500,7000]

plot = ax.barh(city,values)

plt.yticks(city,fontsize=15)
plt.show()
```

Thanks in advance for any help...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could combine the strings with a newline into one string, and use those as labels:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

city = ["Madrid", "Toronto", "New York", "Berlin"]
country = ["Spain", "Canada", "USA", "Germany"]
values = [10500, 9000, 8500, 7000]
labels = [country_i + '\n' + city_i for country_i, city_i in zip(country, city)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(labels, values)
ax.tick_params(axis='y', labelsize=15)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

To have the labels inside the plot, the alignment can be changed to `'left'` and some padding can be added, so the text doesn't overlap with the y-axis. The tick marker lines can be removed setting their length to `0`. (The code below uses dollar signs around the city name, which will render them via Latex, having italics as side effect.)

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

city = ["Madrid", "Toronto", "New York", "Berlin"]
country = ["Spain", "Canada", "USA", "Germany"]
values = [10500, 9000, 8500, 7000]
labels = [f'{country_i}\n${city_i}$' for country_i, city_i in zip(country, city)]

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(labels, values)
ax.set_yticklabels(labels, ha='left', fontsize=15, color='yellow')
ax.tick_params(axis='y', pad=-10, length=0)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: labels inside]

To have more control to use multiple text sizes (and colors), instead of using the labels, texts can be placed manually. Newline characters can be used to set a spacing independent of the scaling of the y-axis. A ["blended transform"](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/tutorials/advanced/transforms_tutorial.html) `ax.get_yaxis_transform()` uses "axis coordinates" for the x-coordinate of the text, and "data coordinates" for its y-coordinate.

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.barh(range(len(values)), values)
ax.set_yticks([])  # remove default y ticks
for i, (country_i, city_i) in enumerate(zip(country, city)):
    ax.text(0.02, i, country_i + '\n', transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(),
            fontsize=15, color='yellow', ha='left', va='center')
    ax.text(0.03, i, '\n' + city_i, transform=ax.get_yaxis_transform(),
            fontsize=11, color='yellow', ha='left', va='center')
```

[image: different font sizes]

Comment: @JohanCThank you for your answer :) This solves two Y-axis labelling issue, but how can ı add these Y-axis labels into the bars?(not the values) Or should I ask is that possible to do that? Do you have any idea?

Comment: Dear @JohanC can we assign different sizes to y axis labels? Instead of making city names Italic, is it possible to use smaller size for city names?